# Can a recordset be opened in PHP using one call?

Tags: php, recordset

Why is it necessary using 2 functions in PHP for opening a recordset? like:

```
$rc = mysql_query($sq, $db);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($rc);
```

Can a recordset be handled also directly without mysql_fetch_array? What is the disadvantage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns a resource and not data.

You must fetch each row by some way `mysql_fetch_array` can help you to move between the results (between pointers)

Answer (score 1):

The way an SQL query is made, at least at the level of the C library that's used by PHP as an interface between PHP and the MySQL database, goes in two steps :

- Execute the query
- Fetch the results

The `msql_*` functions are more or less based on that C-library *(libmysql, before PHP 5.3 and its mysqlnd)*, and, so, work the same way.

Basically, the `mysql_*` functions of PHP are nothing more than wrappers arround the functions exposed by `libmysql`.

For more informations about the C library in question, see :

- [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html)
- [C API Function Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, because the first is used for database interrogation and the second is used for iteration of the array.